# Computing the dirichlet inverse of $n^a$ for $a>0$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Define $f(n)=n^a , \ a>0$. From wikipedia I know that the Dirichlet inverse is $\mu(n)n^a$ where $\mu$ is the Mobius function. But I can't seem to derive this. My attempt is as follows:

$f^{-1}(n)=-\frac{1}{f(1)}\sum_{d|n,d<n}f^{-1}(d)f(\frac{n}{d})$. But I have no idea how to get from this to the required result.

Comment: Compute $n^a \star \mu(n)n^a$ using the defintion of the Dirichlet convolution. You can also look at the Dirichlet series of $\zeta(s-a)$ and its reciprocal.

Comment: @Gary what I have so far is that $f*f^{-1}=\sum_{d|n}n^af^{-1}\frac{n}{d}=n^{2a}\sum_{d|n}\frac{\mu(n/d)}{d^a}$. I can't seem to show rigorously this is the identity though

Comment: You wrote the convolution incorrectly. Check the definition again.

Comment: @Gary ah I see - now I have the convolution as $n^a\sum_{d|n^a}\mu(n/d)$. How do I complete the proof?

Comment: You have $d|n$ and not $d|n^a$. Note that you can replace $n/d$ by $d$ in the argument of $\mu$ (why?). Then see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function#Properties

Comment: These lecture notes contain some important theorems about the Dirichlet Product, and the last theorem may be what you are looking for: https://strings.lums.edu.pk/lecture9.pdf